# Repeater ItemCommand does not work on large data

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

I have a webform that shows a list of items using a repeater and there is a Edit button associated with each item. 
By clicking the Edit button, the page is redirected to the Edit page

### Html

```
<asp:Repeater ID="r epeaterRequest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' CommandName="Edit" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### Code Befind

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            List<MyItem> data = new repository().getData();
            repeater.DataSource = data;
            repeater.DataBind();
        }
    }

 private void repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     int itemId;
     if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out itemId))
     {
         if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
         {
             Response.Redirect("~/Edit.aspx?id=" + itemId, false);
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is that when the number of list items gets larger like 2800 items in the `List`, it halts after clicking the `Edit` button. The ItemCommand does not get called or takes too long to get to the ItemCommand function. 
(Loading and rendering the data is quick. It halts when the `Edit` button is clicked.

Everything is okay when there are less items like 1000.

I've tried adding this `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="300"  />` to `Web.Config` but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add some simple paging to your repeater.  That is a lot of data to load into the DOM at once.  See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31819/Pagination-with-Repeater-Control) for an idea.

Comment: I thought about it but there was no problem loading and rendering the data, so I haven't tried it yet. I was originally using `UpdatePanel` and a search textbox so that the list narrows down as user types a searchstring but removed it to see if it will fix the problem. I could use paging and give a search option too if the problem here is simply the size of the data.

Comment: I had the same issue returning .pdf's, at first it was fine but once there were over about 1200 items returned crazy stuff happened.  I modified it to use paging and its working great again.  and the page loads much faster also.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your LinkButton to simple hyperlink?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="r epeaterRequest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# Eval("href") %>'>Edit</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I think it is better solution in your case. Caz' you are doing the same, but using another way.